# html2canvas missing top image on click

Tags: jquery, html, html2canvas

Using html2canvas to create image but i am facing some issues. when i click `save png` button then it convert into image but missing top image. i have added jsfiddle

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/6460/) for full code

**js code**

```
$(function() { 
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#widget"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                // Clean up 
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

when i click on `save png` button it show this img
[image]

but i need this

[image]

you can see that top image are missing